# Append a text to file?

Tags: python, io

1. How to check that the file exists?
2. How to append a text to the file?

I know how to create the file, but in this case, it overwrites all data:

```
import io

with open('text.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    file.write('text!')
```

In `*nix` I can do something like:

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ -f text.txt ]
    #If the file exists - append text
    then echo 'text' >> text.txt; 

    #If the file doesn't exist - create it
    else echo 'text' > text.txt;  
fi;
```

Comment: `open('text.txt', 'a', encoding='utf-8')`

Comment: This seems to be Python 3.x, since you use the `encoding` parameter to `open()`.  Right?

Comment: I used search and could not find the answer!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use mode `a` instead of `w` to append to the file:

```
with open('text.txt', 'a', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    file.write('Spam and eggs!')
```

Comment: Thank, I could not find the key `-a`. Tell please, how to check that the file exists?

Comment: Why do you want to check if it exists? Are you appending to it only if it doesn't already exist, which doesn't make sense?

Comment: @Wooble, just want to know how to do it. One of the solutions for *nix: `if os.path.exists(filename):`