# How to use linux command "cat" from a script?

Tags: python, linux, subprocess, cat

**Input:A.fasta**

```
>A
sldkfjslkdcskd
```

**Input:B.fasta**

```
>B
pofnvkweu
```

**Expected output:A_B.fasta**

```
>A
sldkfjslkdcskd
>B
pofnvkweu
```

**Code:**

```
my_model_dir_path='../my_model'
word='.fasta'

for f in os.listdir(my_model_dir_path):
    if word in f:
        subprocess.call(["cat", f"{f}"])
```

**Error message:**

```
No such file or directory
```

I used subprocess to call linux command `cat` to concatenate fasta files in a fasta format like expected output. However, I got a message like `No such file or directory` even though the files and the directory exist in right path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`os.listdir` returns a path relative to the given directory.
So, you are try to cat a file at `./A.fasta` instead of `../my_model/A.fasta`.

Try this:

```py
for f in os.listdir(my_model_dir_path):
    if word in f:
        subprocess.call(["cat", f"{my_model_dir_path}/{f}"])
```

If you are using python3, [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) is useful.

```py
from pathlib import Path

for f in Path(my_model_dir_path).glob("*.fasta"):
    subprocess.call(["cat", f"{f}"])
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems likes file path was missing the working directory part.
Also using `tail` makes things a bit less difficult

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import os
import subprocess

CWD = os.getcwd()
files = [f for f in os.listdir(CWD) if str(f).endswith(".fasta")]
subprocess.run(["tail", "-n", "+1", *files])
```

`cat` is probably not the best tool to use in this case.
But if you really want to use cat, then I would suggest to do it like this:

```
for f in files:
    file_path = CWD+"/"+f
    subprocess.run(["echo", f])
    subprocess.run(["cat", file_path])
```

I might be wrong, but it doesn't really makes a lot of sense to call bash from python, when it can be done within python as well.

```
seq = ""
files = [f for f in os.listdir(CWD) if str(f).endswith(".fasta")]
for f in files:
    seq += ">" + f + "\n"
    fasta = open(f'{CWD}/{f}', "r")
    seq += fasta.read()
    fasta.close()
out = open("A_B.fasta", "w")
out.write(seq)
out.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

I am uncertain why you'd want to exec a new command (cat) to do this when you can use Python's built-in file operations to do it instead.

[Append a text to file in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9297557/append-a-text-to-file-in-python)

Answer (score -3):

I saw this post: https://www.delftstack.com/howto/python/python-cat/

```
import os

os.system("echo 'Hello! Python is the best programming language.' >> ~/file.txt")
os.system("cat ~/file.txt")
```

Output:
Hello! Python is the best programming language.

Comment: Don't use `os.system()`, it's insecure. If you *must* exec a command on your host use `subprocess`.